# How do I find the MySQL my.cnf location

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there a MySQL command to locate the `my.cnf` configuration file, similar to how PHP's `phpinfo()`  locates its `php.ini`?

Comment: on ubuntu, you may use the command `locate my.cnf` to find where are all such file names are

Comment: You might need to install `locate` using: `sudo apt install locate`

Answer (score 710, accepted):

There is no internal MySQL command to trace this, it's a little too abstract.  The file might be in 5 (or more?) locations, and they would all be valid because they load cascading.

- /etc/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
- [datadir]/my.cnf
- ~/.my.cnf

Those are the default locations MySQL looks at.  If it finds more than one, it will load each of them & values override each other (in the listed order, I think).  Also, the `--defaults-file` parameter can override the whole thing, so... basically, it's a huge pain in the butt.

But thanks to it being so confusing, there's a good chance it's just in /etc/my.cnf.

(If you just want to see the values: [`SHOW VARIABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html), but you'll need the permissions to do so.)

Run `mysql --help` and you will see:

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

[image]

Comment: `mysql: unknown variable 'defaults-file=...`

Comment: Make sure to restart MySQL server after editing my.cnf: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.

Comment: For me (AWS EC2 Ubuntu), `my.cnf` is located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: If you did `brew install mysql` in OSX, it is probably in `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Run `mysql --help` and you will see

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf `

Comment: @hanxue I forget every time, and your comment reminds me every time :D thanks!

Comment: in my case there was an symlink `etc/mysql/my.cnf` pointing to another symlink `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` which points to `etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

Comment: for ubuntu 16.02 it is located under /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
Refer this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-etc-mysql-my-cnf-is-empty

Comment: `ls /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

Comment: In my case it was in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` (MySQL 1.7.5 on Ubuntu server LTS 18.04)

Comment: In my case (MacOS, mysql Ver 8.0.16), there isn't a `my.cnf`.

Comment: Really noob question but what does /etc mean?

Comment: That is the name of a folder.

Comment: In my case it was hidden in \ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
It wasn't even shown on my default options.

You can easily find your file with MySQL Workbench.
Just go into Server > Options File and there on the bottom you have full path to your used config file like for example:

"Configuration File: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"

Answer (score 233):

You can actually "request" MySQL for a list of all locations where it searches for my.cnf (or my.ini on Windows). It is not an SQL query though. Rather, execute:

```bash
$ mysqladmin --help
```

or, prior 5.7:

```bash
$ mysqld --help --verbose
```

In the very first lines you will find a message with a list of all my.cnf locations it looks for. On my machine it is:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/usr/etc/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

Or, on Windows:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini
C:\Windows\my.cnf
C:\my.ini
C:\my.cnf
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.cnf
```

Note however, that **it might be the case that there is no my.cnf file at any of these locations**. So, you can create the file on your own - use one of the sample config files provided with MySQL distribution (on Linux - see `/usr/share/mysql/*.cnf` files and use whichever is appropriate for you - copy it to `/etc/my.cnf` and then modify as needed).

Also, note that **there is also a command line option `--defaults-file`** which may define custom path to my.cnf or my.ini file. For example, this is the case for MySQL 5.5 on Windows - it points to a my.ini file in the data directory, which is not normally listed with `mysqld --help --verbose`. On Windows - see service properties to find out if this is the case for you.

Finally, check the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html - it is described there in more details.

Comment: Looked promising but on my distro (opencsw.org), there is not mysqld.  It runs mysqld_safe.  "mysqld_safe --verbose --help" is not recognized.

Comment: when I ran it, I got this: `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf ` -- I expected the first 2 files in reverse order.

Comment: The information posted by `mysqld --help --verbose`contradicts what's stated in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html. In my "recent as of today" experience with version 5.6, the information in the website is the most correct and relevant. The priority of the files location given by the help command is misleading and will lead to negative results.

Comment: On my old Fedora it was mysql --help --verbose

Comment: Note that I had to increase the cmd buffer size to 3000 to be able to actually see the first lines, otherwise the text was simply overwritten. When they say "verbose", apparently, they mean it.

Comment: On Windows, I only found it under %programdata% /Mysql/Mysql Server 8.0/my.ini

Comment: I worked around the "too much output" problem with `mysqld --help --verbose | grep -a1 'given order'`

Answer (score 78):

You could always run find in a terminal.

```
find / -name my.cnf
```

Comment: it's the hard way :(
Is there any mysql command like the phpinfo() to know the config file location ?

Comment: `find / -name my.cnf` is your best bet, but you could also check your home directory and /etc/mysql/my.conf

You can also see if your MYSQL_HOME is set by typing `echo $MYSQL_HOME` in a terminal

Comment: Wow, that would take forever on most machines.  Most modern linuxes have locate installed and so long as updatedb is run regularly you can do a:
locate my.cnf | less

Comment: This only shows what files are named my.cnf.  It doesn't tell you which on the mysqld process found and opened.

Comment: This doesn't find `~/.my.cnf` -- note the leading dot in the file name.  Also running a find over the entire file system will usually generate scads of "Permission denied" errors unless you are root.  So the find command should be `find / -name '*my.cnf' 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I think you need `sudo`, otherwise you might get a log of permission denied.

Answer (score 41):

```
mysql --help | grep /my.cnf | xargs ls
```

will tell you where `my.cnf` is located on Mac/Linux

```
ls: cannot access '/etc/my.cnf': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '~/.my.cnf': No such file or directory
 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

In this case, it is in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
ls: /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory
ls: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: No such file or directory
ls: ~/.my.cnf: No such file or directory
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

In this case, it is in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: Why is this not the answer?

Comment: I know I am late to the party - but what if my.cnf doesn't exist anywhere?

`ls: /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory`
`ls: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: No such file or directory`
`ls: /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory`
`ls: ~/.my.cnf: No such file or directory`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. The rest were waste of time. To avoid an error message, use it this way: `mysql --help | grep /my.cnf`. I am using centos.

Comment: Me too. This one worked for me, but leave off the /. Used:

`mysql --help | grep cnf`

result: order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Answer (score 37):

You can use :

```
locate my.cnf
whereis my.cnf
find . -name my.cnf
```

Comment: Great mine was at /etc/mysql/my.cnf in Ubuntu 12.0.1 on EC2

Comment: `whereis` won't work here; it searches for the locations corresponding to a *command*, and can't find arbitrary files.

Comment: And updatedb to update the list locate goes through - if my.cnf wasn't indexed

Answer (score 27):

This might work:

```
strace mysql ";" 2>&1  | grep cnf
```

on my machine this outputs:

```
stat64("/etc/my.cnf", 0xbf9faafc)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4271, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
read(3, "# /etc/mysql/my.cnf: The global "..., 4096) = 4096
stat64("/home/xxxxx/.my.cnf", 0xbf9faafc) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So it looks like /etc/mysql/my.cnf is the one since it stat64() and read() were successful.

Answer (score 14):

By default, mysql search my.cnf first at /etc folder. If there is no /etc/my.cnf file inside this folder, I advise you to create new one in this folder as indicated by the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html).

You can also search for existing my.cnf furnished by your mysql installation. You can launch the following command

```
sudo find / -name "*.cnf"
```

You can use the following configuration file with myisam table and without innodb mysql support (from port installation of mysql on mac os x maverick). Please verify each command in this configuration file.

```
# Example MySQL config file for large systems.
#
# This is for a large system with memory = 512M where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 64M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 16: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: If you want to change mysql configuration in ubuntu 16.04

Edit the following file

`For Ubuntu 16: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Answer (score 10):

As noted by konyak you can get the list of places mysql will look for your `my.cnf` file by running `mysqladmin --help`. Since this is pretty verbose you can get to the part you care about quickly with:

```
$ mysqladmin --help | grep -A1 'Default options'
```

This will give you output similar to:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Depending on how you installed mysql it is possible that none of these files are present yet. You can `cat` them in order to see how your config is being built and create your own `my.cnf` if needed at your preferred location.

Comment: But I do not find the .cnf file in the mentioned location but all other files are present

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan - The list is a set of paths that will be checked, they may not all be present.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how you've setup MySQL on your Linux environment but have you checked?

- /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 7):

Try running `mysqld --help --verbose | grep my.cnf | tr " " "\n"`

Output will be something like

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: That is the output I receive but that appears to have no relation to the running instance. None of those files exist.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a Mac with Homebrew, use

> brew info mysql

You'll see something like

```
$ brew info mysql
mysql: stable 5.6.13 (bottled)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/
Conflicts with: mariadb, mysql-cluster, percona-server
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13 (9381 files, 354M) *
```

That last line is the `INSTALLERDIR` [per the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can also run this command.

`mysql --help | grep cnf`

Comment: Awsome!, on windows I had to replace `grep` with `findstr`:
`mysql --help | findstr cnf` and it did the magic

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Debian/Ubuntu system and already equipped with modern versions of the database (everything from 5.7 up, also true for mysql 8) the best way to locate the actual `.cnf` file I have found is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config my.cnf
```

You should see a output like this:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative my.cnf (providing /etc/mysql/my.cnf).

  Selection    Path                        Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf       500       auto mode
  1            /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf       500       manual mode
  2            /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback   100       manual mode
* 3            /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf         300       manual mode
```

There are two lines in `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` that it makes sense to pay attention to:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

MySQL will go watching for all `.cnf` files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`, then all files in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`

Happy tuning!

Comment: Tangential to the original question, I have the impression it's better to **add a .cnf file** to mysql.conf.d than to edit any existing .cnf file. I have seen a convention to name it <username>.cnf but I prefer to name it <purpose>.cnf such as system_timestamp.cnf Not only (1) because a reinstall could overwrite changes to an existing file, but also (2) a look at the directory reveals the tweaks, and (3) they are portable if changing hosts. I also have the impression `mysql.conf.d` is newer than `conf.d`.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that although mariadDB loads configuration details from the various my.cnf files as listed in the other answers here, it can also load them from other files with different names.

That means that if you make a change in one of the my.cnf files, it may get overwritten by another file of a different name. To make the change stick, you need to change it in the right (last loaded) config file - or, maybe, change it in all of them.

So how do you find all the config files that might be loaded? Instead of looking for my.cnf files, try running:

```
grep -r datadir /etc/mysql/
```

This will find all the places in which datadir is mentioned. In my case, it produces this answer:

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
```

When I edit that file (/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf) to change the value for datadir, it works, whereas changing it in my.cnf does not. So whatever option you are wanting to change, try looking for it this way.

Comment: grep -r datadir /etc/mysql/ saved me a lot of time , thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Found mine using

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

Answered for only MySQL Workbench users,

[image]

Comment: Got an error "Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified"

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the whereis command.

E.g. whereis my.cnf

Comment: You'd probably be better with 'locate' if the system supports it.

Answer (score 2):

All great suggestions, in my case I didn't find it in any of those locations, but in `/usr/share/mysql`, I have a RHEL VM and I installed `mysql5.5`

Answer (score 2):

I installed xampp bundle with `apache, php and mysql` in **ubuntu**. There `my.cnf` file is located in `/opt/lampp/etc/` folder. Hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to look through the various locations depending on your version of MySQL.

```
mysqld --help -verbose | grep my.cnf

For Homebrew:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11)

Default possible locations:
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf

Found mine here: 
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (direct edit) :

```
$ sudo nano /etc/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Comment: on ubuntu 18, this one works for me:  `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are in a VPS and are trying to edit a my.cnf on an already running server you could try:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

You will be show the parameters the mysql command is being run and where the `--defaults-file` points to

Note that your server might be running more than one MySQL/MariaDB server's. If you see a line without `--defaults-file` parameter, that instance might be retrieving the configuration from the .cnf's that are mentioned on `mysqladmin --help` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can find my.cnf or any other file with find command:

```
find / -name my.cnf (or any other file name)
```

1. find is a command
2. / (slash) is a path
3. my.cnf is a file name

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, access Templates > MySQL (my.cnf) > [version]

If you are running MAMP windowless you may need to customize the toolbar using the Customize button.

[image: MAMP PRO Templates Menu]

Answer (score 0):

for me it was that i had "ENGINE=MyISAM" kind of tables , once i changed it to  "ENGINE=InnoDB" it worked:)
in PhpMyAdmin on Azure App Service :)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your access right but for me
this work on phpmyadmin sql console

SHOW VARIABLES;

then after to change some variables
you can do

SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;

or

SET @@GLOBAL.max_connections = 1000;

give a try

Answer (score 0):

MySQL configuration file:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysql --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

Answer (score 0):

For *MariaDB 10.5* on *Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)*:

```sh
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
```