# MySQL tab completion not working

Tags: mysql

In mysql client, it used to show possible words when I press tab. Somehow it is not working now. Is there anyway to enable it again. I'm using mysql client 5.5 in CentOS 5.5.

Comment: On mysql prompt, `rehash` does the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found the solution.

in my.cnf file, add

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

add `no-auto-rehash` to disable auto completion.

Comment: That's what the docs say, but this doesn't work for me at all. I've tried writing `[mysql] auto-rehash` in `my.ini` and supplying `--auto-refresh` to the `mysql` command line program, to no effect.

Comment: @mcandre what version of my mysql server you are using?

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.10, for Win32 (x86)`

Comment: @mcandre the above solution worked well with linux. I'm not sure about windows :)

Comment: The completion in mysql client relies on the readline library, which is ubiquitous on linux/unix systems, but rarely found on windows systems. If you installed cygwin, mingwin or similar, and used the mysql shell inside those environments, you would get command completion. I'm not sure about getting a 'native' readline library for windows, but I suspect it would not help since the windows mysql client would not have been compiled against it.

Comment: find my.cnf here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915033/8526184