# how to set bulk_insert_buffer_size in mysql?

Tags: mysql, variables, global-variables, myisam

I want to set bulk_insert_buffer_size variable for insert. I searched from other pages too, all they are saying about my.cnf. But there is no my.cnf in my system. I checked my.ini and there is no such variable there.

I also tried through command line -

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size= 268435456;
```

It shows -

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size =1024*1024*256

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.002 sec
```

but on running -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%bulk%';
```

I am getting the same(old one) -

```
Variable_name            Value    
bulk_insert_buffer_size  8388608
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.
I am using Mysql 5.5 version.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

confusing. it is not changed in GLOBAL, but changed in SESSION. I also use MySQL 5.5, CentOS, 64Bit. anyway if you want set this value permanently, add `set bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M' and restart.

```
mysql> show variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 268435456 | <= initial value
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 268435456 | <= not changed with GLOBAL
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set session bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 1048576 |  <= changed with SESSION
+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) says `bulk_insert_buffer_size` can be modified while MySQL running (`Dynamic Variable` = yes). SESSION and `GLOBAL`ly changable.

[image: bulk_insert_buffer_size]

### UPDATED

IF `bulk_insert_buffer_size` is changed via GLOBAL, It seems that not affect SESSION variable (still confusing). To see, use "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLE", "SHOW VARIABLES" implies "SHOW SESSION VARIABLES"

```
mysql> show session variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 2097152 |
+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 1048576 |
+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show  variables like '%bulk%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 2097152 |
+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what is the difference between session and global? 
Does that means this value will be set for only one session?

Comment: @Aamir0731 Hello, `SESSION` means set for current connection. if client A "SET SESSION xxx = 1", only makes it sense to client A. But `GLOBAL` means if someone "SET GLOBAL xxx = 1", it effects all connections.

Comment: done!! :) thank you
ok but what if I want to change it permanently for my live server? i dont think so session gonna work there? correct

Comment: @Aamir0731 You're very welcome! I have updated my answer. (see bottom of it).

Comment: >add `set bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M' and restart.
where i can set this?
and sorry i did not understand your last point about dynamic variable= yes

Comment: @Aamir0731 probably this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location