# MySQL from Deb changing configuration after installing perl packages?

Tags: mysql, sidebar

This will sound silly, I'm sure. Here goes.

I have a new installation of Debian Wheezy (Debian7). Instead of going with the aptitude installation of MySQL that right now holds v5.5.31 I went with the deb-package from MySQL to get the latest stable release (currently 5.6.15).

After a little tweaking and adding of my.cnf it worked fine. All was well. However, I wanted to utilize some statistics tools that rely on Perl, so I did the following

```
 sudo aptitude install libdbi-perl
 sudo aptitude install libdbd-mysql-perl
```

Having done that, I now get the following error when trying to start MySQL:

```
 service mysql start
 Starting MySQL
 [FAIL] Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe) ... failed!
```

This is really peculiar to me since I have mysql installed in the default dir for deb-packages i.e. /opt/mysql/server-5.6/ and before the installation of perl DBI and mysql-support for perl it all was working just fine. Did the perl-mysql bindings screw with some global configurations? I don't have the /usr/bin/mysqld_safe path set anywhere that I know of.

Any help at all would be great. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a distinct possibility.  MySQL has some unfortunate "helpful" things that will cause it to find configuration files you don't want it to find.  What directory is the correct (existing) my.cnf in?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the shell command

`locate my.cnf`

to find all any my.cnf files that are on your filesystem

also - see this answer:
[how to know mysql my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location)