# MySQL sort_buffer_size

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have received this error:

```
Bad SQL query Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_659_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

So, following [this suggesttion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53201/mysql-creates-temporary-tables-on-disk-how-do-i-stop-it), I try to edit:

```
sort_buffer_size=4M
join_buffer_size=4M
```

But I can not find them. Where are they located on Ubuntu 14.04 machine? There are no such options in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command `find / -name my.cnf` on the terminal.This would work as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location/9603176#9603176)

Comment: I have /etc/mysql/my.cnf. But I can not find sort_buffer_size=4M. Do I need to add them to my.cnf?

Comment: you would need to ..:)

Answer (score 0):

try finding the location of `my.cnf` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9603176/634958)

Secondly i think the title of this question should be:

> Where to find my.cnf in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the values in the running instance you could do (just fire it as a query from anywhere):

```
SET @FourMegs = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = @FourMegs;
SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = @FourMegs;
```