# Mac Big Sur MariaDB will not run

Tags: mysql, mariadb, homebrew, macos-big-sur

MariaDB has worked fine but is now failing to run on boot up. I have uninstalled and it then reinstalled it and this does not fix anything.

Here is the output from `mysql.server.start`

mysql.server start

```
Starting MariaDB
.210913 10:08:11 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxx-MacBookPro.local.err'.
210913 10:08:11 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (4944) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

This is what I get from `brew info mariadb`

```
mariadb: stable 10.6.4 (bottled)
Drop-in replacement for MySQL
https://mariadb.org/
Conflicts with:
  mariadb-connector-c (because both install `mariadb_config`)
  mysql (because mariadb, mysql, and percona install the same binaries)
  mytop (because both install `mytop` binaries)
  percona-server (because mariadb, mysql, and percona install the same binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.6.4 (902 files, 183MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-09-13 at 09:49:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/mariadb.rb
License: GPL-2.0-only
==> Dependencies
Build: bison ✘, cmake ✘, pkg-config ✘
Required: groonga ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, pcre2 ✔
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To have launchd start mariadb now and restart at login:
  brew services start mariadb
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Analytics
install: 13,312 (30 days), 41,010 (90 days), 166,455 (365 days)
install-on-request: 13,289 (30 days), 40,949 (90 days), 165,680 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Here is what I get from `brew services list`

```
dnsmasq   stopped                  
httpd     error   xxxx /usr/local/opt/httpd/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mariadb    xxxx /usr/local/opt/mariadb/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
mysql@5.7  xxxx /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx     stopped                  
php@5.6   stopped                  
php@7.0   stopped                  
php@7.3   stopped                  
php@7.4   stopped
```

The mac is serving up PHP successfully which throws a "Connection Refused" error when the code tries to talk to the database. So, I don't really understand the httpd error if apache appears to be operating.

Here is the contents of the err log (thank you DanBlack)

This is from the /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxx-MacBookPro.local.err

```
2021-09-16T15:30:12.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/XXXX-MacBookPro.local.pid ended
210916 17:30:13 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2021-09-16 17:30:13 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd (server 10.6.4-MariaDB) starting as process 33244 ...
2021-09-16 17:30:13 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2021-09-16 17:30:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
210916 17:30:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/XXXX-MacBookPro.local.pid ended
2021-09-16T15:30:21.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/XXXX-MacBookPro.local.err'.
2021-09-16T15:30:21.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2021-09-16T15:30:21.651835Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-09-16T15:30:21.652151Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2021-09-16T15:30:21.652197Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35) starting as process 33337 ...
2021-09-16T15:30:21.655210Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-09-16T15:30:21.656555Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-09-16T15:30:21.656576Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-09-16T15:30:21.656585Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-09-16T15:30:21.656593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-09-16T15:30:21.658530Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-09-16T15:30:21.658624Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-09-16T15:30:21.659813Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-09-16T15:30:21.668320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-09-16T15:30:21.719277Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Only one log file found.
2021-09-16T15:30:21.719324Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error not found
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233348Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233372Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233382Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233390Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-09-16T15:30:22.233402Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-09-16T15:30:22.233770Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This keeps repeating every few seconds.

However, I can now connect to the localhost mysql server and run things using mysql databases @ 127.0.0.1 having deleted /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile0

Comment: I do not know brew but there is the path "/usr/local/opt/mariadb" and "/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7" but in the first part of the post there is "/usr/local/bin/mysql". Are you sure that the paths/start scripts are correct? Maybe you have to remove the (old) configuration since reinstalling maybe does not change existing configurations...

Comment: This solution has worked for me. 

https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/a74766108b4630fc5c7c822df23526e8

Problem is I'm not sure why this is.


By deleting `/usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile0` mariaDB starts to work. 

Anyone with an explanation of why this happened or why is solves the problem?

Certainly seems that /usr/local/bin/mysql is involved though

Comment: Don't go deleting or manipulating database files to fix problems. 99% sure it isn't solved, you've just created a new problem. Include `/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxx-MacBookPro.local.err` contents in your question.

Comment: Interesting answers here: Not sure if it answers the uqestion "why" though:  [Getting error "Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed" when starting MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439742/getting-error-plugin-innodb-registration-as-a-storage-engine-failed-when-sta)

Comment: Yes, interesting. I will investigate when I have time to.

Answer (score -3):

Ran into the same problem. Mariadb was conflicting with a previous mysql installation on my M1 mac.
Removed `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/` folder and reinstalled mariadb. Works fine now.

Comment: You delete all the database data by doing this, be careful