# Can't connect to mysql on non standard port

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-5.7

So I've recently upgraded to mysql 5.7 from 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I can't connect to mysql if I use a port other than 0 or 3306. So `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1` and `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306` work, but if I try `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 19300` I get

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I suspect I started the mysql server wrong, but I'm not sure what I should do differently.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you be able to expect to connect to the MySql Server on an arbitrary port? 3306 is the bound port in the default configuration.

Comment: Please post your /etc/my.cnf MySQL server configuration. Have you correctly specified the port there? http://askubuntu.com/questions/407847/how-to-change-mysql-port-number-in-ubuntu

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm not as familiar with mysql as you are, that's why I'm here. Please be patient.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Turns out I don't have one. Maybe it got deleted when I upgraded? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603176/2256053 I'll make one and try adding the port numbers when I get a chance.