# Error: Broken Pipe/MySQL Server has gone away

Tags: mysql, database-administration

MySQL throwing Broken Pipe and MySQL Server has gone away errors. My database table contains text fields where I insert large HTML in every 1 hour periodically.

Which MySQL variable should i consider to set.

Here is current configuration:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/monk/mysql
socket=/home/monk/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
default_time_zone='+06:00'
innodb_buffer_pool_size=35G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=15
query_cache_type=ON
query_cache_size=64M
join_buffer_size=524288
tmp_table_size=32M
max_heap_table_size=32M  


# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
max_allowed_packet=1G
# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

wait_timeout = 2000
interactive_timeout = 2000



#bind-address=127.0.0.1
##skip-networking~
```

Comment: Interesting, I had a similar problem and set max_allowed_packet to 64M to fix it but you have it set to 1G!  How big is that HTML anyway?  You can double check the value of max_allowed_packet in your mysql session with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: HTML is not more than 25Kb in size.

Comment: Every time I have to restart MySQL to resolve this error but it comes after 2-3 days again.

Comment: I would verify the max_allowed_packet in your connection's session, and also do a `ps aux | grep mysql` to verify you are looking at the right my.cnf file (I believe mysqld checks the directory defined in the `--basedir` parameter).

Comment: @Clayton: Show variable returns this output `1073741824` for max_allowed_packet.

Comment: ps aux | grep mysql output : `--basedir=/usr --user=mysql`

Comment: the my.cnf you are looking at is at `/usr/my.cnf` ?.. or where is the location of the my.cnf you posted?

Comment: Location of config I posted : /etc/my.cnf

Comment: is there a my.cnf anywhere in /usr??

Comment: actually, check this link to get an idea of where my.cnf could be located: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/747678

Comment: I also could be totally wrong about it reading the incorrect my.cnf file but just trying to understand how max_allowed_packet is set to a high number yet you mysql is going away.

Comment: mysql config only located at :`/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: crap, well, I'm out of ideas!  Have you tried to adjust the timeout values as suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7942309/747678

Comment: Already set this value to 2000 .

Comment: are you using extended inserts or simple inserts?

Comment: I am using extended insert statements, which may contains upto 20  value sets .

Comment: if you change to simple inserts does it fix it? yeah, it'll be slightly slower but since max_allowed_packet looks okay looking for a viable workaround.  Are you using the latest version of mysql?

Comment: Yeah... It may resolve the issue but this thing not limited to the inserts , I am also receiving errors in selects statements of this data and some times MySQL dynamic SQL queries also fails in which I am using session variables to store temporary query

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: 5.6.x? ..?  Perhaps do an upgrade?  What is in your mysql error log?  This is the closest I found in MySQL's bug list to your problem http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74400 - it suggests to change the thread_stack setting (it is for 5.6.21).

Comment: MySQL Version 5.6.25

Comment: Well, besides doing an upgrade or finding other potentially useful error messages in the error log I'm out of ideas and I have to get going.. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, max_allowed_packet should be 256MB is enough and you may have a slow network connection. try the below variables also.

set net_write_timeout to double and 
increase net_buffer_length also in a rally.

Also How much ram you have in your box, are you taking all to innodb_buffer_pool, set this upto 70 to 80% of your box ram.

One more advice is to turn off query cache as it is a web stuff.