# MySql full text search 2 characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using MySQL FullText Index Search on my system and when I search with 3 characters the query works well but when I search with 2 characters the query returns null.

I use this query:

```
select * 
from table 
where MATCH (description) AGAINST ('+gp*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I already use this command `show variables like 'ft%'` to get the value of `ft_min_word_len` and the value is 4. It is strange that with 3 characters the query works.

However i tried to change this value on file /root/.my.cnf. (I use Ubuntu 14.04 and server pilot). I add this to the file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
```

Restart the mysql, drop index and create index.

Although when I execute this command again `show variables like 'ft%'` the value still remains 4.

How do I use mysql full text search with 2 characters?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct location of the my.cnf?

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location)  or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html#mysql-configuration)

Comment: Thank you so much @mkey! I'm so stupid :) I'm following this link (from server pilot)-> https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-access-mysql-with-the-mysql-root-user.html and it isn't the correct file!
I owe you one beer! :D