# Find and edit mySQL config file in wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, config

I have a wordpress site which I am managing using C-panel. I want to edit "ft_min_word_len" in MySQL config file. However, I don't seem to be able to find it. Do i need to do such edits in the wp-config.php file? If so, how?

Comment: No, they are to be made in the mysql config file, check in one of the default locations listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). Most likely under `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: I cant find it anywhere in the files. Is there a way to get it not using the file explorer?

Comment: @Solarflare I crawled through all the sites directory and cant find a .cnf file

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/863110

Comment: @IsaacDj The mysql config file is not in the sites directory (assuming you mean everything accessable through the browser or the wordpress admin panel). Try `ssh` or `ftp` to login (I'm not sure what you mean by file explorer, the cpanel file manager might show it under `/etc` if you have access to it). If you use a shared hosting service, you probably cannot change the mysql options yourself. Are you able/allowed to start and stop your mysql service? You can try to just add a config file in one of the mentioned locations.