# Remote MySql Can Connect using Navicat but Not From Another Host

Tags: mysql, remote-connection

Hello I have a centos server and I have succeeded setting remote connection from software like Navicat on windows, remoDB on android. But the problem is, I can't connect to the server from my other hosting.

here is my code sample

```
<?php
$servername = "******";
$username = "***";
$password = '*****';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and the error i got is this

```
Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '*****' (111 "Connection refused")
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to specify a 'db_name' after 'password' ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about "other hosting"? I guess it's not localhost.
Maybe you have used "over ssh" connection when you used Navicat, so that why it was not denied.

**111 error** reflects "connection refused", it means that your mysqld only listens to the localhost.
Solution: you need to edit (or comment) `bind-address` value in the mysqld section of your my.cnf file (check “[how to locate my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location)”?)

- comment this line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
- then restart mysql

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am not using over ssh connection in navicat or remodb (android app). I've been searching my.cnf file on my server, I only found one in /etc/my.cnf and there are only few lines, and there is no bind-address value.

Answer (score 0):

Another guesses :
Try to specify db_name, port, socket:

- make sure you use the right port : `mysqladmin -u {user} -p{pwd} variables | grep port`
- make sure you use the right socket : `mysqladmin -u {user} -p{pwd} variables | grep sock`
- Then proceed like this:
  `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db’, ‘xxxx’, ‘{path to my socket}/mysql.sock’);`

Comment: Not working either bro, I don't know what is the problem here. I telnet to the server with port 3306, the connection was established.