# Getting ip_adress and port_number where MySQL is running

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL to create database using ubuntu. I downloaded and installed MySQL in terminal and I create database and insert data on it.
Now, I have to select the ip_adress and the port number where MySQL is runing.
But, I don't understand how to get these informations.

Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: MySQL default port for TCP/IP connections is 3306, and if you installed this on the same machine, then the server name is usually just `localhost` or the local IP address, `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get an error when using these informations: <console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found. 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: _Where_ are you trying to put this information? Config file of a certain system/software? What does the documentation of that says about in what format it expects this?

Comment: I am using spark shell to load data from MySQL to HDFS. So, I have to put the ip adress and the port number of MySQL before loading data to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

the default port of mysql is 3306 and the ip you get from you pc or just use LOCALHOST(127.0.0.0.1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When using 127.0.0.1:3306, I get this error: <console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found. 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: where you are putting this ip?

Comment: I am using spark shell to load data from MySQL to HDFS. So, I have to put the ip adress and the port number of MySQL before loading data to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `ifconfig` command to get the ip address of the machine
- As far as port is concerned, the default port for MySQL is 3306. However, you can change this via `my.cnf` file (if you have't changed it then it will be 3306). [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location) how to find `my.cnf` file location.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used 'ifconfig' to get ip adress and then I put the default port for MySQL 3306, but it shows this error:            '<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
       127.0.0.1:3306'

Comment: I am using spark to load data from MySQL into Spark. So, I start the Spark shell using this command: 'spark-shell', then I have to put the ip address and port number. '127.0.0.1:3306' but it shows this error:      scala> 127.0.0.1:3306
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
       127.0.0.1:3306
            ^