# Cannot see any of /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf in my dir

Tags: mysql, terminal, server, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to find file `my.cnf` per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location) post. With one of the answers there I typed  `mysqladmin --help` after ssh ing into my remote server.

Part of the output:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

So from my root, I typed `ls -la` to see all files:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul 18 02:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Jul 17 14:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3637 Apr  9  2014 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul 17 14:09 .cache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jul 17 14:09 .cloud-locale-test.skip
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1004 Jul 18 02:03 .mysql_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  675 Apr  9  2014 .profile
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul 17 14:06 .ssh
```

There's no etc folder to look for my.cnf. Where would this file be?

Answer (score 0):

I think your current folder is wrong, using command *pwd* to know where you are. From your root, try cd to those folders, then use ls -la:

```
cd /etc
ls -la

cd /etc/mysql
ls -la

cd /usr/etc
ls -la
```

Comment: Hi I'm in my root dir and there is no etc folder.

Comment: Which version of EC2 are you using? I'm using EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04 and etc folder is included. It's strange if there is no etc folder.

Comment: well, from your answer, you didn't try "pwd" :))

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc <-- is a directory
/etc/my.cnf <-- is a file
/etc/mysql <-- directory
/etc/mysql/my.cnf <-- file
/usr <-- directory
/usr/mysql <-- directory
/usr/mysql/my.cnf <-- file

~/ <-- ~ special notation to indicate home directory of the current logged in user
~/.my.cnf <-- user specific config for MySQL
```

You can edit the files and change directories to the directories.

```
cd /etc
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

The location of your specific config is dependent on how you installed mysql. If you used apt-get I believe its located in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Therefor to edit the file you could run:

```
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

typically ~/.my.cnf is used for User-specific options. Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574609/why-do-i-not-see-my-bin-var-etc-directories-in-my-root-partition). I am in the root directory not / (confusing).

```
cd /
```

Then I could see directory.