# MySQL database IP address from rackspace or google cloud?

Tags: php, mysql, rackspace

Ok here’s the deal. I setup MySQL database on Rackspace and I’m trying to connect to it. I am using the tutorial google maps to create store locator using MySQL. The line of the code in the tutorial asks for the host name and I’m giving the IP address of my server on Rackspace. I’m using what I think is the correct one but it’s not working. Any ideas?

Here's the google tutorial code:

```
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
};

My code:
$connection=mysqli_connect ('THE IP ADDRESS OF MY RACKSPACE SERVER', 'MY USERNAME', 'MY PASSWORD');
```

Here's a link to the tutorial from google: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

I know I have the server IP correct and my username/password correct since I'm able to login via SSH from terminal with those credentials.

When I use mysql> \s to show the status it says Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket - does this mean it's local host? I need it hosted on IP to connect right?

Comment: If your PHP web server is hosted on the same server as your database, it will be typically be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` While logged in through SSH, mysql will report as localhost, as that is how you connected to it. You would need to check your [`my.cnf` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location), and ensure the server is able to accept external connections from `IPTABLES` on the port configured in `my.cnf`

Comment: Any time you see a "tutorial" that begins with `$connection=mysql_ ...` walk away.  Find another tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that your MySQL server is by default by your Linux distribution's packaging configured to listen either locally, or on the socket file only. You can update your DB config to listen on the public IP address of your server however obviously this can come with some security implications.

To do this edit the /etc/mysql/mysqld.conf file (this may be in a slightly different location depending on distribution being used) and the following line as such...

From

```
#bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
```

Now restart your MySQL service using the systemctl or service command.

```
service mysql restart
```

Your MySQL server is now listening on ALL the host's IP addresses. If you want to limit it to just one you should enter that IP instead of 0.0.0.0. You should now be able to connect to your MySQL server remotely, however, you must have already configured your database user to be able to login from the webserver. If you haven't configured the user yet do something like this.

```
mysql
CREATE USER '<username>'@'<webserver ip address here>' INDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database>.* TO '<username>'@'<webserver ip address>';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You should now be able to login as this user and view / modify / insert etc... data to the database specified from the server IP address specified. You can test this from the web server using the MySQL client like this...

```
mysql -u <username> -h <db server ip> -p
```