# pgloader - Failed to connect to mysql at "localhost" (port 3306) as user "root": Condition QMYND:MYSQL-UNSUPPORTED-AUTHENTICATION was signalled

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgloader

I am trying to migrate my rails application from mysql to postgres. Since we have already running application so I am moving mysql data to postgres database using pgloader. But when I do

```
pgloader mysql://root:root_password@127.0.0.1/mysql_database postgresql://postgres_user:postgres_pass@127.0.0.1/postgres_database
```

**I get error - Failed to connect to mysql at "127.0.0.1" (port 3306) as user "root": Condition QMYND:MYSQL-UNSUPPORTED-AUTHENTICATION was signalled.** I can easily log in to mysql from terminal though.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782

Comment: Right, pgloader is not able to make connection with mysql 8.x. I need to downgrade mysql to 5.x

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that currently *pgloader* doesn't support `caching_sha2_password` authentication plugin, which is default for MySQL 8, whereas older MySQL versions use `mysql_native_password` plugin. The corresponding issue is opened on [Github](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782).

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782#issuecomment-502323324), the workaround here is to edit `my.cnf` (if you don't know where it is, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9603176/6609485)) and in `[mysqld]` section add

```ini
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Then restart your MySQL server and execute:

```sql
ALTER USER 'youruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';
```

After that the error must be gone.

Comment: I tried this but the error still remains with MySQL 8.0.32 Homebrew. The `ALTER USER` command returned `Query OK, 0 rows affected`, is that to be expected?

Comment: @RichardKranendonk The command output is totally fine.
Are you sure that you are using the same right credentials? I mean username, password, server, port, etc.

And you can check the current authentication plugin by executing `SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;`

Comment: plugin for root is mysql_native_password; mysql.infoschema, mysql.session and mysql.sys use caching_sha2_password

Comment: @RichardKranendonk Could you check the current server plugin then: `sudo mysqladmin variables | grep default_authentication_plugin`?

Comment: Returns: `default_authentication_plugin | caching_sha2_password`

Comment: @RichardKranendonk That's the point. It must be `mysql_native_password` after the changes. Either you haven't edited `my.cnf` file or you haven't restarted the MySQL server. Please follow my instructions exactly.

Comment: This solution just doesn't work for me.  I'm running mysql in a docker-compose situation and the docker-compose.yml file specifies `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`.  I took the suggested steps nevertheless, and it didn't work.

Comment: @tadasajon It looks like the command is not complete. I haven't tested my solution with _docker-compose_, but could you check [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782#issuecomment-1000153539)?

Comment: This worked for me. I followed the exact steps.