# How do I correctly restart mysql so that changes in the `*.cnf`-files get active?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux-mint, erpnext

I try to configure mysql as mentioned here: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-erpnext-erp-platform-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts-with-nginx-mariadb-support/ on a Linux Mint 18.2 system.

I added `innodb-file-format=barracuda` to the `[mysqld]` section in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` and restarted the mysql service. But these settings are taking no effect.

If I run following commands

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_format';
```

then I get following output.

```
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| innodb_file_format | Antelope |
+--------------------+----------+
```

The settings file `~/.my.cnf` is not existing.
Why are my settings taking no effect?

**++++++++++++ UPDATE 2019-06-03 ++++++++++++**

I think I found the issue now. `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` is the correct logfile and the settings were not overwritten by another `*.cnf`-file. After a restart of the PC, the changed settings were used. The problem is, that restarting the mysql service (`sudo service mysql restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`) is not enough.

So the question should be:

How do I correctly restart mysql so that changes in the `*.cnf`-files get active?

Comment: Did you try to find my.cnf in these locations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location

Comment: Yes, I checked all locations. But it seems I found the issue now. `sudo service mysql restart` was not enough to overtake the changes in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`. I had to restart the PC so that the changes get used. How do I correctly restart mysql?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to find `my.cnf` in other locations like

[How do I find the MySQL my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location)

If no luck, scan all `*.cnf` files in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` because Mariadb may read all `*.cnf` as config in that folder

Therefore you may add this value on `50-server.cnf`, but it is overwritten in another files

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But please take a look at my updated question. The issue seems not to be with the `*.cnf`-files.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
systemctl restart mysqld
```

Instead, do:

```
systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

Not sure exactly what the syntax is for Debian's 'service' command but I believe that's just a wrapper around systemctl. Syntax should be easily found. Change the service name if your system uses something different, of course. I have found that for some services, doing a restart doesn't seem to reread the config files, while a stop and then start forces a complete reload and config file read.