# XAMPP MAC OSx - use external USB drive for MySQL storage

Tags: mysql, xampp, xampp-vm

I'm using fairly large MySQL DB Tables with XAMPP, which makes it tough with my rather small internal storage of my Mac. I thought I would just keep MySQL data on an external USB3.0 SSD drive, but it looks like it's not that easy.

Here is what I've tried:

1. With XAMPP ( not VM ): Moved /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql to /Volumes/myexternalssd/mysql and then pointed everything in my.cnf to that dir. The permissions seem to have copied properly. But it didn't work. MySQL does not start at all if I trash the original dir, or just keeps using the original dir if I leave it in place.
2. With XAMPP-VM: Moving ~/.bitnami dir to the ext drive and then symlinling ( ln -s ) to the new location. The error is then:

   Cannot load stack definitions.

Dtails:

```
1 error occurred:

* failed to create stack: cannot deserialize stack from file "/Users/arseni/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/metadata.json": open /Users/arseni/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/metadata.json: operation not permitted
```

Comment: I don't see why variant 1 should not work. Sounds like you edited the wrong `my.cnf`.

Comment: This seems to me to be a dba question

Comment: @GhostGambler This is the one I edited: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf

Comment: I haven't used XAMPP in years, therefore I cannot tell details. I would check the logs and startup parameters of mysql, and the default locations of `my.cnf`. This answer might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/3340665. Especially `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%'` might help.