# vi and nano do not work in a container, all files are not displayed through the ls command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, nano

i'm starting mysql containter
`docker run --name l4-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-pass -p 3305:3306 -d mysql`
after i'm bash him
`docker exec -it l4-mysql bash`
need to edit mysqld.cnf file, but when i try use nano or vi i have error
bash: nano: command not found
bash: vi: command not found
Other than that, I don't see the actual file in the directory /etc/mysql i have only another dir

```
bash-4.4# ls
conf.d
```

I tried to install nano inside bash (in ubuntu itself it is installed and working), I get an error

```
bash-4.4# apt install nano
bash: apt: command not found
```

Comment: (1) You can't install a software in a **shell**. You can only install it on a platform and then use it from a shell. (2) As you see from the error message, `apt` is not in your PATH. Try to specify the path to _apt_  explicitly.

Comment: @user1934428 nano working in ubuntu, but not working in bash

Comment: _ubuntu_ is an operating system distribution, _bash_ is a shell. You are comparing apple with pears. What operating system is your bash running on?

Comment: @user1934428 Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What does it mean that _nano does not work_? How do you run _nano_, and what response do you get?

Comment: This is about a Docker container. Depending on the base image, `apt` might be available or not. It is more likely that it is not and you need to use `apk` instead. The host operating system does not matter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql build the image with oracle linux so to install nano or vim you run the command

```
microdnf install nano sudo -y
```

and the location of my.cnf file is answered here [the MySQL my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location)