# Running mysql in chroot

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, chroot

I've got a chroot environment working on my 10.04 ubuntu box. I'm trying to run mysql inside this chroot environment, but I get this error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Basically I used debootstrap along with schroot to create the chroot. Then I installed "ubuntu-minimal" and mysql-server inside this chroot environment. If you are interested here are all the steps that I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot . But mysql does not work inside the chroot. /var/log/mysql.log and /var/log/mysql.err files are empty and mysqld server is running. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug with schroot. mysqld escapes chroot and interacts with systems's mysqld.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625863 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/430224

Comment: And was this bug fixed? Is there a workaround? What to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

make sure mysql have write permission. 
try running mysql   as root.
 If it works fix the file permission so mysql have write permission and restart mysql as normal user. .

Comment: I am inside chroot as a root. So thats not a problem.

Comment: can you list the package you have installed for mysql and 
file permission of /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: @neo, hopefully you aren't running mysqld inside the chroot as user `root`. (That would make any chroot security useless; running mysqld as root makes shivers run up my spine.)

Comment: I simply installed `apt-get install mysql-server` in the chroot. And /var/run/mysqld directory is empty.

Comment: @sarnold - Yep, I'm doing it as root, but just for the time being. Atleast it should start working and then I can change the permissions.

Comment: than follow the instruction here 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=276470&page=2
see the #17 post

Comment: @vivek - Interesting. If I just create that sock file and restart my mysql, the error number changes to 111. `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`. And If I run mysqld with root, I get access denied error.

Comment: @Neo try this and let me know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Comment: @vivek - Now, mysqld when run as root works. So I guess touching the sock file did a trick. Now onto figuring out the file permissions ;).

Comment: @Neo, it sounds like you are trying to solve a problem you don't need to solve.  If you know you will eventually want to make it run as a non-root user, why are you spending time and energy trying to get it to run as root?

Comment: @dj_segfault - mysqld 'does' run as root. So atleast thats working. It doesn't work when run with normal permissions i.e. non-root.

Comment: @sarnold - mysqld interacts with system's mysqld even without root permissions. Its a bug.