# MySQL remote connection problem "system error: 111"

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server installed on windows 2003 machine.  When I try to connect to this server remotely with PHP, it gives "system error: 111" error, but when I try to connect using commmand prompt or using mysqlyog, it always connects.

works well this command

```
mysql -h 192.168.0.10 -u root
```

and here is the php code

```
<?
    session_start();
    $PHPSESSID = session_id();

        define("DB_SERVER", "192.168.0.10");
    define("STOCK_DB", "stock");
    define("MASTER_DB", "masterstock");
    define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_PREFIX", "mlc");

        function makeconnection()
        {
                $link = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
                if (!$link) 
                {
                        die('Error while connecting to MySQL : ' . mysql_error());
                }

                $db = mysql_select_db(MASTER_DB, $link);

                if (!$db)
                {
                        die ('Can\'t Open Database : ' . mysql_error());
                }
        }

?>
```

****Edit: Please note, I am able to connect locally, able to connect remotely using command prompt ****

Any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Comment: No, not a duplicate, becuase in my case I am able to connect using command prompt or mysqlyog.  I am getting this error when I try to connect with PHP remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the hosting,  and they fixed it.  Actually, **port 3306 going outbound was not open**

Comment: Glad to hear that you have it all figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your firewall is not blocking the port.

Comment: I am trying to go thru the simple things first :). the symptom looks very much like the remote communication is being blocked. Odds are the server firewall is blocking the communication port.

Comment: but what about the thing that I am able to connect using mysqlyog and command prompt :)

Comment: Are you able to connect from a remote machine that way?

Comment: Ya, I am able to connect to it using command prompt and even mysqlyog