# Can't connect Ruby on Rails to remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to connect my rails 3 app to a mysql database hosted on a godaddy server. I am able to connect remotely using a mysql client, but not when I run the applicaton. I was able to connect on a local mysql, but when I try to connect to my remotely hosted database I get this error:

> Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on '[host ip address]'
>   (111))

Here is my database.yml

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    host: host_ip_address
    port: 3306
    database: database_name
    username: user_name
    password: password
```

I'm developing my application on an Ubuntu machine if that helps.

Comment: have you tried messing with or asking GoDaddy about your socket setting? (/tmp/mysql.sock)

Comment: You wouldn't be using a socket to connect to a remote DB. @Tony, it looks most like the remote DB is refusing connections from anything by localhost. How did you connect to the remote db with the mysql client? Can you update your question with the command and response? One thing you could try to get over the hump is setup a ssh tunnel to the mysql host and connect through that.

Comment: @pduey I connected using mysql workbench with had no trouble, and I used the same host, port #, username, and password. I've never used ssh tunneling before; I'll do some research and try that out, and let you know if I get anywhere.

Comment: @gominimal I haven't resorted to speaking with GoDaddy support yet. I'm on a cheap cloud hosting plan, and my experience is whenever have an issue they tell me to upgrade to a more expensive dedicated hosting plan.

Comment: Correction to above comment (I guess you read it correctly anyway) - remote DB is refusing connections from anything *but* localhost. If you try connecting from the command line (or are you on windows?) you will get better diagnostics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that, per my original comment, your remote DB is refusing connections from anything but localhost. Based on that assumption, here are two solutions:

1. Use a ssh tunnel. There are tons of howto's for connecting over ssh tunnel, e.g., http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/.
2. Make sure your remote DB is accepting remote connections. Check out the accepted answer on the following stackoverflow thread [Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)

Comment: Thanks alot the SSH tunnel connection worked. I had to enable ssh connections on my server, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

- In your `my.cnf`, look for this line:

  ```
  bind-address = 127.0.0.1
  ```

  and set address to `0.0.0.0`
- Access `mysql`:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p
  ```
- Than create a user on `mysql` server and grant privileges to all:

  ```
  CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'WITH GRANT OPTION;
  ```