# Force wordpress to connect to database over TCP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to connect wordpress running on my machine to a remote mysql database which is tunneled on my machine(localhost). The database connection works by giving following parameters to `mysql` CLI client

```
$ mysql --protocol=TCP -P 10000 -h localhost -u username -p'password' db_name

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 93438893
Server version: 5.5.8-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+-----------------------------------+
| Database                          |
+-----------------------------------+
| information_schema                |
| db_name                           |
+-----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (1.38 sec)
```

In `wp-config.php` file of wordpress, I have tried the following values:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', 10000);
```

this doesn't work & throws the following error:

```
Warning: include(/home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-content/advanced-cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-settings.php on line 62 
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-settings.php on line 62 
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1038
```

the last line in the above error(`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket`) is gives it away why the connection fails as wordpress is trying to connect through an unix socket.

Now, what parameters I need to set to be able to get wordpress to connect to database way as `mysql` CLI client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was able to connect using the following settings in `wp-config.php`.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:10000');
define('DB_PORT', 10000);
```

the database connection was successful :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to connect via TCP instead of the Unix socket, try changing the host from `localhost`, to `127.0.0.1`.

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');  // forces TCP
```

Comment: Tried

But that too generates an error: `Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1038` Any more ideas?

Comment: Error 111 means access denied, did you add a user that is allowed to connect via TCP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Comment: I was able to to figure it out, thanks for suggesting `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost