# SSH port Tunnel for MySQL works with mysql command line but not WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I created an SSH port tunnel:

```
ssh -f -N -L 3306:localhost:3306 myuser@thedomain.com
```

On that same machine where I created the port tunnel, I can connect to mysql by doing:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p
```

On that same machine, if I try to make Wordpress connect to MySQL, **none** of the following work:

```
/** MySQL hostname - NONE of these work */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
//define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
//define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
//define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306');
```

Why can't WordPress connect?

I tried restarting `httpd` but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: because mysql specialcases `localhost` and turns it into a local unix-domain socket connection. That means it won't be a TCP connection at all, and comlpetely invisible to your port forwarding.

Comment: @MarcB Other people have successfully set up WordPress with SSH tunneling for the DB, so i know it's possible. Can you tell me what I could do to make it visible as normal?

Comment: your 127.0.0.1 SHOULD have worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743654/force-wordpress-to-connect-to-database-over-tcp

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what specifically happens? Do you get any error messages? Timeouts?

Comment: If this is for establishing a secure connection, then it might be worth checking MySQL's docs about establishing secure connections. If it isn't, ignore this comment and I'll remove it later.

Comment: @Kenster All I see is WordPress says it cannot conect to that database and that it might mean it's down.