# Zend framework 1.11 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, zend-framework

My application zend framework does not connect in the bank, but a simple php script connects successfully.

Error zend framework
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

My simple php script

```
<?
 $banco = "database_test";
 $usuario = "root";
 $senha = "1234";
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$usuario,$senha);
 mysql_select_db($banco) or die( "fail");
 if (!$conn) {echo "error"; exit;}
 else {echo "Sucess.";}
 mysql_close(); 
?>
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.10. In ubuntu 11.10, my zend framwrok application worked.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

login as root and do

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

it might be a permissions thing

Comment: I already tried that, but when I run the command, I get               $setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
Cannot set persistent booleans, please try as root.
Could not change policy booleans
rudy@rudy-pc:~$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: record not found in the database (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: could not set record value (No such file or directory).
Could not change boolean httpd_can_network_connect
Could not change policy booleans

Comment: then refer to this documentation for further steps, it involves adding a registry key and rebooting http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111