# MySQL server connection works from command line but not from perl script using DBI

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm able to connect to a remote MySQL server from command line using

```
mysql -h "mysqlhost" -u user -ppasswd
```

But when I try to connect to the same server through perl script I get the below error:

```
DBI connect(.....)failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysqlhost' (111)
```

My code looks like this:

```
use DBI;
use DBD:mysql;
my $DBH = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=DB1;host=mhsqlhost", "user", "passwd") ||   die "Connection Failed: $DBI::errstr";
```

Any inputs would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try dropping the second line

Comment: What about the typo in hostname? (mhsqlhost -> mysqlhost)

Comment: The host name is just mockedup. I'm using the actual hostname in my script. Tried dropping "DBD::mysql;" Didn't help.

Comment: Is the database name correct? That didn't seem to be present when connecting from the shell

Comment: When connecting from cmd line, after entering the mysql prompt I can give "use DB1;".

Comment: Is mysql only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) or is it listening on all hosts? Can you access mysql through the hostname that you're attempting to access it from in your script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420854/223226

Comment: The mysql server is running on a remote server and not on local host.

Comment: mysql -h mysqlhostname -u user -ppasswd -e "show databases;"  works absolutely fine from my m/c(lets say myhost) cmd line. If run the perl script(connecting to mysqlhostname using DBI) from myhost, it erros out.

Comment: Providing the port in the connect() call solved the problem, even its the default port.
DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=DB1;host=mhsqlhost;port=3306", "user", "passwd") ||   die "Connection Failed: $DBI::errstr";

Comment: what's the output (error message) you get when you run your script?