# EC2 w/Elastic IP Connection Refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, firewall

I have a fixed IP attached to my EC2 instance. 
I am able to test the connection with nc as follows.

```
$ nc -v **.***.***.** 3306
Ncat: Version 6.25 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

But,

```
$ nc -v **.***.***.** 22
Ncat: Version 6.25 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to **.***.***.**.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
```

In my security group I have two rules:

1) Inbound 22 from 0.0.0.0/0

2) Inbound 3306 from 0.0.0.0/0

What am I missing?

Comment: Is MySQL/MariaDB up and listening on that IP? Try to verify it with `nc` locally on the EC2 instance.

Comment: `$ nc -v 127.0.0.1 3306`
`Connection to 127.0.0.1 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`
`[`
`5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1VT"K6g)3��bvJP2IWY<^Dzmysql_native_password` Looks like it's connecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found that answer to this.

I was under the impression that in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I simply had to comment `skip-networking` (which does not appear in MySQL my.cnf past a certain version). Turns out you also have to comment out `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1` .

nc threw me off, I thought the problem was at the firewall. I'll still be happy to accept as a correct answer anyone who can shed light on what `bind-address` achieves.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111