# Connect to mysql not from localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my website's mysql from my VDS, the following code does not work, what is the secret?

```
<?php

$db_host = "WEBSITE.COM";
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "pass";

mysql_connect("".$db_host."", "".$db_user."", "".$db_pass."") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected!<br />";

?>
```

Comment: what is the mysql_error() message? and why using `"".$db_host.""` instead of just `$db_host`?

Comment: Why do you concatenate your variables with empty strings?

Comment: "Does not work" does not define what is wrong.. we need to know what is wrong.

Comment: Error says:

"Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"

Comment: I thought every function's argument must be quoted.

Comment: @user1804119 - No, that's not necessary :-)

Comment: Ok, so I get Error 111, mysql server is running, vars are correct, what is next, I've googled that port might be needed, how do I use it and what port is used?

Comment: Maybe MySQL at your VDS Hoster is configured to only accpet requests from particular hosts. You can tell MySQL to only accept packets from particular IP addresses. So you probably have to use an IP address instead of your domain name.

Comment: Oh, so I should contact them? Because there is no information on their website (http://serveriai.lt). :/

Comment: It's up to you ;-) But normally every hoster should provide you with the credentials you need.

Comment: Well, It's Lithuania, everything is not normal here usually.

Comment: Where do you have your MySQL username and password from? Probably there you will find your IP address. And often hosters have something like a 'How To'-page with an example how to connect.

Comment: I found the IP(https://lokys.serveriai.lt/), but it does not work still.

Answer (score 2):

Without more details on the error it's hard to guess, but if I have to guess I'd say your username is only allowed to connect from localhost. Mysql users have both a username and a host, and both must match for the connection to be allowed.

You could create another user allowed to connect remotely with something like `CREATE USER username@'your.ip.address' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password'`

And then granting him access to the databases you want (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Another thing to check would be that the port mysql is using (3306 by default) is open to the outside world and that the mysql server is listening on all interfaces (see your my.cnf config file).

Comment: But what I'm wanting to do is to grab information from VDS.Mysql ant insert it to Website.Mysql, so if I'd creat another user, it wouldn't have my  database.

Comment: Yes it would, if you grant him access, using the GRANT command I pointed you out to :)

Comment: It says
"#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation "

Answer (score 2):

As you posted what error code is, i recomend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111) topic. I believe, that answer is there ;)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not the owner of the server I'm trying to connect. I only have a hosting plan. So I can't access that file.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to connect from the outside? Where is your .php file hosted?

Comment: Well I have a server where I upload files and I have a website where I post links to those files, I want to create program that does it all automatically, so I should get the name, the link and some other props from my VDS mysql and insert it to my website's database.

Answer (score 2):

Probably MySQL at your VDS Hoster is configured to only accpet requests from particular hosts. You can tell MySQL to only accept packets from particular IP addresses. So you have to use such an IP address instead of your domain name.

If you don't know that IP address **The only solution is to contact your hoster**, IMHO.

Comment: Well, I guess then I have to do it the other way, upload the script to my website and make a connection to VDS that I own.