# Ruby, connect to sql server

Tags: mysql, ruby, sql-server, dashing

I'm trying to connect to a SQL server in a domain, but I don't know why I have an error.

My environnement is Ubuntu 14.04, and I use mysql2. 
I think my problem is `:server="myServer"` but I have to specify what server.

My request is :

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",:server="myServer" ,:username => "myname", :password => "SECRET", :port => 3306, :database => "test" )
```

which gives me this error: `Mysql2::error (111)`

This request is working:

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "192.168.1.1", :username => "root", :password => "SECRET", :port => 3306, :database => "test" )
```

Comment: Using the `Mysql2` driver directly is probably a bad plan. What are you trying to do? A layer like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) helps considerably when interacting with a database.

Comment: @tadman, +1. I agree about Sequel. It's a great way to go when talking to a database. Look at the Sequel [home page](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), [README](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) and [cheatsheet](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) to get an idea of how it can make life a lot easier.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a MySQL SQL-based server, or a MS "SQL Server"? It looks like you're trying to connect to a MS SQL Server, so  why are you using the mysql2 gem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)

Probably you are facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you try connecting through your terminal? Without using mysql2 gem? (mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password mydb) If so, there were any errors?