# Allowing MySQL to receive remote connections

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been searching the web for hours trying to find a solution for allowing remote connections to MySQL on Ubuntu 14.02. I have done everything I have seen that you can do. Every manipulation of bind-address possible, commenting it, changing its value to `*` or `0.0.0.0`. I have granted privileges to both root and to a user that I created named `admin`, and every time I am getting a `111` error. I just don't understand why it's not working. I have done EVERYTHING I can possibly find via Google with no results.

```
sudo netstat -plutn | grep -i sql                                
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      9329/mysqld
```

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Comment: Probably be better served on Serverfault since this isn't coding related.  Whats the exact error message you recieve when trying to bind to an address?  Instead of grepping on SQL, grep on 3306.

Comment: @AllInOne I have already tried all of the solutions in that topic.

Devon I honestly don't know what grepping is. And the the only error I can see is the 111 error