# Redmine 3.2 on Bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, bluehost

I've just completed for installing Redmine 3.2 on BlueHost. However, an error message has accursed "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111) (Mysql2::Error)". I really do not know what is root cause?

Explanation:
- Assigned full privileges for user database
- I can connect to mysql database via console
[# rails generate controller First list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AC6i.jpg)
and  you can take a look
[Redmine on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydz6x.jpg)

I do not know what is wrong? I appreciate all your suggestions,

Thank you,

Comment: Could it solved by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420862/57091)?

Comment: Should I assume that you did create a config/database.yml and modified it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed successfully Redmine 3.2.0 on BlueHost (Shared hosting).

1) You will need SSH

2) You all can follow the document on BlueHot at [Ruby On Rail How to install](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/redmine)

3) You will get error page as mentioned above. And then you will fix it by adding following lines to config/database.yml (Ex. production)

reconnect: true

socket: mysql

port: 3306

4) Run again:  "bundle install --without development test"

5) Go browser and try again

Good luck!