# MYSQL on Debian: what's the real host name?

Tags: mysql, debian, hostname

When I was connecting to the database I always used "localhost" as a host name.
Now I want to connect to my MYSQL database from Windows program and I have to use the real IP instead of localhost.

I tried to use the server IP and IP from this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'
```

But both don't work. How can I check the real IP adress, which can be used to connect to MYSQL DB?

MYSQL database was installed on my Debian server without any special settings I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the user table in MySQL.

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

Check either they have privileges to connect remotely or not.

Also check `bind-address` in configuration file, it has to be commented.

Comment: After using this command I got 127.0.0.1, localhost and my server IP. Nothing else.
How can I check the privileges to connect remotely?

Comment: Is that you want to connect from dynamic IP or static IP

Comment: If you want to connect from dynamic IP then you need to set the host  to %

Comment: I set the host to % for user "lo" - in my case. But still I can't connect to the database. When I run your command, this % exists for this username.

Comment: Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_server_ip' (111)

I've found the error. You were right. I did this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Problem solved.