# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (111)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

It is impossible to connect to mysql that I setup with phpmyadmin on a debian 8 VPS. I have been searching for hours, I have even followed this guide http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html but nothing, it seems imposible to get to connect to it, I even have created a phpmyadmin profile that is not on localhost and on %...

Thanks a lot for helping...

Comment: Do you have a user in the mysql database, that is allowed to connect to mysql from localhost/your ip?

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to open the connection.  Have you checked that you can connect with the `mysql` client program?  If not, then it's likely not a programming problem, and therefore off-topic for [so] - see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

111 means connection refused, so make sure your mysql config is correct, and check your firewall.

Mysql config details (from [Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)):

If you have lines like this :

```
skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

In your my.cnf configuration file, you should comment them (add a # at the beginning of the lines), and restart MySQL.

That's the first thing to try. Then try turning off any firewall and connecting again. That will tell you whether there's a firewall problem.

Comment: You can change the bind to `0.0.0.0` to open to everything, but that's not always enough. Turning off the firewall permanently is extremely risky, so be sure to turn it back on after.