# Raspberry pi3 Mysql Python ERROR

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Hi I'm trying to connect from python to MySQL but I can't apparently due to below error. I tried it with this...

```
import MySQLdb
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user     ='phpmyadmin',
                      passwd   ='raspberry', 
                      host     ='192.168.0.58',
                      database ='freddy')

print 'connected'
cnx.close()
```

and then i changed "Mysqldb" to "Mysql.connector" but doesnt work.  This is the error showing :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 2, in 
>       cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='phpmyadmin',passwd='raspberry',host='192.168.0.58',database='freddy')
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>   TypeError: 'database' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>   ....

what should i do? i know my password its fine, but must be somethig else...

Comment: Finish the tour and check in a bit how I reformatted your question to fit the requirements of SO.

Comment: im using rasbian.

Comment: If one of the provided answers worked for you please select it as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word `database` should be `db` and then you should be fine and connect.

Change your loginpart into below code:

```
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user   ='phpmyadmin',
                      passwd ='raspberry', 
                      host   ='192.168.0.58',
                      db     ='freddy')
```

This gives you oversight of used keys and values. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: i did it, now is showing this error : 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
 cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='phpmyadmin',passwd='raspberry',host='192.168.0.58',db='freddy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'192.168.0.58\' (111 "Connection refused")')

Comment: That's another question.. did you check if this is posted as a question on SO? The traceback in your comment should be posted as new question if nothing can be found. Or you could have posted it like: `Traceback: OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'192.168.0.58\' (111 "Connection refused")') `.

Comment: Check if your user/pass credentials are captial sensitive server-side and if the `db` is named correct as you provided in your posted code. Also, turn on debugging, eventlog or errorlog server-side to see what's going on. This is error is server-side and not Py!

Comment: my user name and pass are fine, beacuse i cann acces by the browser , and also if i do mysql -u phpmyadmin -prasberry i can acces to maria db, but the error keep showing.

Comment: euhm... `db = 'freddy'` vs. `db = 'maria'`... makes sense ;-)

Comment: Check also `MySQLdb` db-settings if the are set as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420862/8928024). Don't forget to reboot afterwards.

Comment: i tried both... db = Maria and db = MariaDB, not working either, btw when  i want to install "sudo apt-get install  python-mysql" showing this: 
E: Unable to locate package python-mysql

Comment: try at the command-line `pip install <packagename>` but do first `pip search mysql` to get a list with packages and select correct packagename.

Comment: i tried 
pip install python-mysql     and this is showing me 

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-mysql (from ver               sions: )
No matching distribution found for python-mysql

Comment: its $sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb for python 2.7. For python3 $sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb. Or pip equivalents but search with the word `mysqldb`. My typo to miss-out on the 'db' letters.

Comment: you can also try `apt-cache search mysql|grep python` to find the correct wording this way..

Comment: keep showing me the error 111 like before, i dont know what more to do. i've installed all you said and nothing mate...

Comment: did you check the settings of the db in MySQL database and if you made changes... did you reboot?

Comment: uhmm i dont know what i can change in the db settings to be honest, also i dont know how to acces there.

Comment: Did you read Pascal Martin his answer about the MySql server? Find my.cnf file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/8928024) is described and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Ranaivo shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529285/8928024) where you have to write the code.

Comment: yes i saw it, everything its commented exept by those 2 lines:

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

Comment: Raaivo  post, his my.cnf  lines are really differents than mine i got less than his.

Comment: No problem if you have less. Different setup... ;-) Use '#' to disable `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/` and `!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/`. Then it should work...

Comment: still the same error dear friend..    everything its commeted in my "my.cnf"  documented...

Comment: can i give you my teamviewer id? so you can check it really quickly if  u dont mind... dear friend

Comment: its better to post it as a separate question on SO for the experts. I stretched my knowledge here on what I ever tried to get a mysqldb inlog working again. Got an arduino around but no berry atm. Otherwise I could go through the process with you... Last shot... have you tried login as admin or root? This could reset some privilages on the server-side as I recall.

Comment: dammmmm man...... its working now!!!! you really helped me man!!! thanks so much for your time!!!!   its been hard this for me. but now works ....  thanks, i follow Ranaivo post.

Comment: Wohooo... great its working... don't forget to feed the fish "usefull answer" ;-)