# Cant connect remotely centos on mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I've tested everything, and every possible way.
I already disabled iptables, I did everything myself.

I gave joker permissions on all users and database in mysql.

And anyway, how can test https://cp.nationwarriors.com/ the error persists:

Fatal error connecting to mysql server.
SQLSTATE [HY000] [2003] Can not connect to MySQL server on '177.87.231.218' (111)

in localhost I get it.
I checked the door is normally open at https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

[image]

Comment: Do you have your server binded to an external ip? Try bind-address=0.0.0.0

Comment: I've done this process too, buddy. And it did not work either.
:(

Comment: Show your my.cnf

Comment: Look my.cnf

http://prntscr.com/ir24gd

Comment: Which firewall 're you using?

Comment: native of the centos, iptables.
Look: http://prntscr.com/ir25ik

Comment: Try disabling it

Comment: is disabled too.
I tried almost everything.

Comment: I would be grateful.
Because I tried everything, and I can not find a logical solution: /
I reinstalled mysql everything, did almost everything.

Comment: let's start from the network: does telnet work? do you receive "connection refused" or a password request?

Comment: ok, i tested it myself, and I am able to connect to your db, i.e. it's not a firewall/network problem. (i'm asked for username and password) at this point, i'm pretty sure it's a privilege problem. try looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a Teamviewer session and a few tests we've discovered that the problem is with the hosters firewall.

You can telnet from every location to the database server, except from the webserver.

Comment: Was solved.
Yvan Watchman found the problem.

Thank you, friend, for the help.