# Remote MySQL Connection Refused

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I'm having a strange problem connecting to a remote MySQL server. Telnet shows the port is open (configured for 3307 instead of 3306), there is no 'bind-address' set in the my.cnf file and all permissions have been granted for both localhost and the IP.

The error returned from the command line is:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '176.35.197.115' (111 "Connection refused")
```

And from a [simple PHP connection script](http://109.203.114.58/~snf/dbtest.php):

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/snf/public_html/remote-db-test.php on line 27
```

Connection refused

The part that is strange is that the [same php connection script from a *different* remote server](http://www.smoke-no-fire.co.uk/dbtest.php) works perfectly?

The server is an old mac running osx10.8 and MySQL 5.6.26

This is the PHP file (IP, username and password hidden for security):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3307", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE demo";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you check other SO post regarding this issue. Maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111 ?

Comment: check is firewall blocking your connection

Comment: Can u post ur connectiong String?

Comment: Does the account have any IP restriction in the privileges, like 'user'@'111.222.333.444' ?

Comment: Apparently there is no firewall on the server (not my server but have been assured this is true).

Comment: I've edited the post with my connection script

Comment: There are three accounts for the user we're trying to use: user@localhost, user@109.203.114.58 and user@%

Comment: Have you checked that MySQL to remote server is connected manually from command prompt before connecting through php program?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, adding the port as a separate argument instead of being part of the host string:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "pass", "dbname", 3307);
```

[PHP documentation link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)