# Can't connect to mysql server on a LAN

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on a django project and I would like to make mysql connection between my machine and another one on remote

`DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'OPTIONS' : { "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;" },
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.33',%the machine which contains mysql server 
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}`

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'192.168.1.33\' (111 "Connection refused")')`

Comment: check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111

Comment: Could be any number of things. Is it running? Is it firewalled? Are you firewalled?

Comment: I check this response and it didn't work .

Comment: Tadman : what do you mean by firewalled ?