# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'l ocalhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)

Tags: python, mysql

I am using **mysql connect** in the **python script**.
Python script needs to work for long time
It works fine for a few hours but it has issues to connect mysql after some hours
Here is my codes.

**Code to connect mysql**

```
host = "localhost"
user = "root"
def get_connection():
  connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=host,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database=database
  )
  return connection
```

**Script repeats below codes to insert the results**

```
connection = get_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(insert_query, records_to_insert)
connection.commit()
posts = cursor.rowcount + 1
cursor.execute("""UPDATE topics set posts=%s WHERE tid=%s""", (posts, topic_id, ))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Could you give me a solution to resolve my issues?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)

Comment: no, it doesn't work for me